# Do I have to use Play App signing to generate sha_256 fingerprints for Android app links? My company releases the app through App Center

Tags: android, react-native, google-play-console, visual-studio-app-center, android-app-links

I've been trying to implement Android app links into my company's react native app, I've been following the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/verify-site-associations) and I'm struggling with the part that involves adding the **assetlink.json** file on my website. I see mention of using **Play app signing**, our company doesn't release through the google play store instead we release through App Center. Hence, why my current google play console doesn't have a fingerprint.

There is also an option to generate a fingerprint with a keytool command but I don't think this is the right move since the fingerprint generated on my machine wouldn't work in production, right?

My question is do we have to use Play App signing to get the proper fingerprints to use for app links? Or is using App Center fine? If using App Center is fine then where can I find the sha_256 fingerprints to put in the **assetlink.json file**?

Comment: I am trying to do the same thing. It appears that in my case, we have our App Center releases connected to Azure DevOps pipelines, which is doing the signing. If you are doing the same thing, you should find a task in the build that is copying a key and or performing the signing. I believe if you are not copying any different App Signing Keys in, it will just be using the project default. I obtained this by running `gradle signingReport` in the `PROJECT_ROOT/android` folder (look for the ones with Config: release)

Answer (score 0):

in the end I ended up downloading the APK from AppCenter and running

`apksigner verify --verbose --print-certs <APK_FILE`

I then used the

> Signer #1 certificate SHA-256 digest:

As the fingerprint.

The `apksigner` is included as part of the Android SDK / Build tools. Working on a mac I found these tools at `~/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/<latest_version>/`